# Path configuration problem with mod_wsgi - WSGIScriptAlias

Tags: configuration, path, mod-wsgi, alias

I'm trying to config the path using WSGIScriptAlias after loading wsgi module succesfully with this line:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/patipol/RTG-Likitomi/likitomi/apache/django.wsgi
```

It works properly for my application but this also caused phpmyadmin at http://localhost/phpmyadmin cannot be found. If I'm not mounting at root so change it to:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /django /home/patipol/RTG-Likitomi/likitomi/apache/django.wsgi
```

Phpmyadmin come back to work again but many links in my code cannot be found such as:

```
<iframe id="map" name="map" src="/inventory/" frameborder="0" style="width:100%; height:500px; margin-top:35px; margin-left:0px;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Location at "/inventory/" cannnot be found. I have to change it to "/django/inventory" to make it works. The problem is there are many links in my code specified like this. Is there another way to solve this by not changing every links in my code? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To still have it mounted at root yet have static files and PHP still work, use technique described in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

instead of WSGIScriptAlias.

For the case of using WSGIScriptAlias and mounting at sub URL, you should not be hard coding absolute URLs in your templates in the first place. Instead you should be using something like 'url' template tag to generate the URL. This way you change things around, or mount application at different mount point and they will all automatically adjust. See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#url

and:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#topics-http-reversing-url-namespaces

and the 'reverse' function for doing same in code.

Comment: According to your provided technique, I've tried using traditional alias instead of WSGIScriptAlias but it still not work for me. Please see my last edition at the bottom of my question.

Comment: You used the wrong example from the documentation. You want the one at the end of the section that uses AddHandler for .wsgi extension and the rewrite rules.

Comment: Dumpletion I'm really confused with the documentation. Could you provide me a full example? Suppose that `django.wsgi` is at `/home/protocole/apache`. What should be found in my `httpd.conf` file.